# CSS : cropping an image makes the text disappear

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I need to have a 100% width image with a menu and a form over it.

After that region I will have the page main content ...

To better adapt the image to different devices I am "cropping" the image on left/right or top using margin and media queries (resize the window to check).

The problem is when I crop the image, for example on top, the header-content goes also up and disappears.

Here is my HTML and CSS with a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/af3toa8r/1/):

```css
.header {
    position: relative;       
}
div.slider {
    position: relative;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    outline: 0;
    height: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    div.crop {
        margin-left: -12em; 
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:800px) {
    div.crop {
        margin-top: -4em; 
    }
}
div.header-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;     
}
div.main-content {   
}
```

```html
<div class="header">    
   <div class="slider">
      <div class="crop">          
         <img class="slide" src="http://placehold.it/800x200"/>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="header-content">
      <div class="menu">
         A menu
      </div>
      <div class="form">
         A form
      </div>
   </div>    
</div>
<div class="main-content">
   Main Content
</div>
```

By removing the "crop" part everything works fine ...

Here is my HTML and CSS for the non crop version [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/f74psw2v/3/):

```css
.header {
  position: relative;       
}
div.slider {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  outline: 0;
}
div.header-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;     
}
div.main-content { }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="slider">
    <img class="slide" src="http://placehold.it/800x200"/>
  </div>
  <div class="header-content">
   <div class="menu">
       A menu
   </div>
   <div class="form">
       A form
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
<div class="main-content">
  Main Content
</div>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The `margin-top: -4em;` opened secret (`;)`) top space for the `.header-content` to move in! (it does not disappear, it just moves to the available area. Thange to `-1em` to get a picture.)

Comment: I know that it is the margin-top that is making the text to disappear. I am using the margin-top because I am cropping the image to better adapt to bigger screens. But how can I change my code to still being able to crop the image without making the text to disappear. That is the question.

Comment: there's plenty of solutions. It's just the way you're *ehrmm* "cropping" your image that's strange.

Comment: So how would your crop the image? The way I am doing is very common ...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan A good explanation of what I am doing: http://designshack.net/articles/css/focal-point-intelligent-cropping-of-responsive-images/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it.

To get the image to crop, you can use absolute position on the image within a container
that has `overflow: hidden`.

You need to make a decision about the height of the `.crop` container, I used `vw` units
with are based on the width of the viewport, but it depends in part on your layout.

You need to adjust your media queries so that the right screen width ranges are
applied, in some cases, you need to set both `min-width` and `max-width` to get the
logic right.

To place the image, adjust the offsets on the image and/or the margins.

**Note:** This approach is very flexible and the exact details (values for offsets, widths, margins) will depend on your actual image and how it is to be displayed at different screen sizes.

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
}
div.slider {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  outline: 0;
  height: auto;
}
div.crop {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25vw;
  position: relative;
}
div.crop img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 480px) {
  div.crop img {
  width: 125%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -60%;
  margin-left: -25%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  div.crop img {
  width: 300%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -150%;
  margin-left: -150%;
  }
}
div.header-content {
  background-color: yellow;  /* for demo only */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
div.main-content {}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="crop">
      <img class="slide" src="http://placekitten.com/1000/1000" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-content">
    <div class="menu">
      A menu
    </div>
    <div class="form">
      A form
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
  Main Content
</div>
```

Comment: Your approach does not work. When you make the browser size small you will have blank space on the left side of the image. That is not the objective.

Comment: A good explanation of what I am doing: http://designshack.net/articles/css/focal-point-intelligent-cropping-of-responsive-images/

Comment: I adjusted the left offset simply to make it obvious that the media queries were working correctly.  You can set the left offset to whatever you need to crop the image within the edges of the `.crop` element.

Comment: @MDMoura I took a look at the DesignShack.net article (nicely written) and you will note that the parent block `.focal-point` uses `overflow: hidden` to crop the edges of the child div/image. Your example does not follow the DesignShack.net example, you inadvertently left out a few key CSS rules to the technique to work.  My solution is similar except that I chose to use absolute positioning instead of relative positioning of the image.  However, the key is that you need to set `overflow: hidden` on the top level block that contains the image.

Comment: sorry I am not sure I get it because when I change the left percentage I always get a blank area on one of the sides.

Comment: @MDMoura I reworked my example to demonstrate how you might use this technique.  If you scale your image to 100% width, then shifting the left or right margins will open up some white space on the left or right sides of the image.  To avoid this, you need to make the image bigger than 100% as I have shown.